# Using the intermediate value theorem for derivatives to infer that a function is strictly monotonic

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity, connectedness

My textbook Elementary Classical Analysis claims that by Darboux's theorem (the intermediate value theorem for derivatives), if a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ has a nonzero derivative on $\mathbb R$, then is $f$ strictly monotonic (i.e., either $f'(x)>0$ on $\mathbb R$ or $f'(x)<0$ on $\mathbb R$).

The claim is definitely true if $f's$ domain were instead a closed interval, but since $\mathbb R$ is open, I don't understand why Marsden's claim should be true.

Comment: A function that is monotonic on every closed interval is monotonic on the whole of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Otherwise, $f'$ would take both a positive value and a negative value.  There is a closed interval containing the points at which they occur. So...

Comment: @DavidMitra Ah! Thanks, would you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argue by contradiction.  If $f$ is not strictly monotonic, then, $f′$ would take both a positive value and a negative value. There is a closed interval containing the points at which these values occur. So...